# Why control location changed in form when the form is building?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a form with some controls like `label`s and `texbox`es in it.every thing is OK but when I build the project the form will repaint and the location of all controls change. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you using `UserControl`s? If you modify a UserControl, then it will only update on the Form that it's used on when you rebuild. Other than that, in what way does "the location of all controls change"?

Comment: Give us your code so we can understand the problem